# How to remotely control Linux services like Jetty, MySQL etc from the comfort of my XP desktop?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, remote-access

I'm wondering if there is some sort of nice control panel app that I could run on XP that would show the current status of services that I'm running on my remote Linux server. You could, with a single click, stop or restart a service. Being able to add custom commands would be a bonus. This is in a development environment where I'm frequently restarting the services to redeploy stuff.

(I'm ok with ssh'ing in and doing 'service restart blah', but it can get a bit tedious.)

Answer (score 1):

It's horrendously clunky and ugly but many people use [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com) for this.

Comment: (Wow, I can't vote up your response because I don't have enough rep. I hate stackexchange sometimes, I really do.)

Yeah, it does look clunky. Probably more useful in a real production environment rather than the development I'm doing.

Comment: ... and I just can't vote Webmin up... that doesn't feel right :S